# Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated with LIMIT 1

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting the following as both an attempt at info-share of best practices as well as a request for additional opinions...)

---

***Q:***  I need to run a query that gets the exchange rate for a transaction. Based on the date of the transaction, I need the latest exchange rate from a rate history table where the starting effective date for the rate is less than the transaction's date.

Very basically:

```
SELECT  t.Amount, t.TrxDate, t.Currency, ex.ExchangeRate
FROM Transactions t
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT ExchangeRate 
    FROM RateHistory h
    WHERE t.TrxDate <= h.EffectiveDate AND t.Currency = h.Currency ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC 
    LIMIT 1) ex
```

The problem comes in with the LIMIT 1. I can't have this subquery returning multiple rows, I only need the most recent exchange rate. Using LIMIT 1 or attempting to use ROW_NUMBER() and a conditional join both result in the same "Unsupported subquery" error.

Anyone have any recommendations? The query works just fine elsewhere, but not in Snowflake.

Here is the actual query. The last subquery is the issue.

```
SELECT
        'SG' AS Region,
        CAST(gl.acct_no AS NUMERIC(12,6)) AS acct_no, 
        gl.trx_date, 
        source, 
        gl.reference, 
        doc_no, 
        gl.amount, 
        for_amt,
        reference2,
        gl.reg_int_id, 
        gl.reg_seq_no, 
        gl.curr_id AS gl_curr_id, 
        c.curr_id AS chart_curr_id,
        z.reference AS reference3,
        z.dist_dt,
        cur.cur_desc,
        ex.exchng_rate 
FROM            gltrx  gl
JOIN            chart c ON ROUND(c.acct_no,6) = ROUND(gl.acct_no,6)
LEFT OUTER JOIN currencies cur ON gl.curr_id = cur.curr_id
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT MAX(ap.reference) AS reference, MIN(aph.dist_dt) AS dist_dt
        FROM    apdist ap
        LEFT OUTER JOIN aphist aph ON ap.voucher_no = aph.voucher_no
        WHERE ap.reg_int_id = gl.reg_int_id AND ap.reg_seq_no = gl.reg_seq_no) z                     
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT Exchng_rate
        FROM    Curr_hist 
        WHERE Curr_Id = gl.curr_id
        AND Exchng_Dt <= gl.trx_date 
        ORDER BY exchng_dt DESC 
        LIMIT 1) ex
```

***Recommendation 1:*** Tried below query with returned one row successfully, both emp and dept tables have two rows each.

```
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE DEPTNO = (SELECT DEPTNO FROM DEPT LIMIT 1)
```

So we can use LIMIT in subquery, there is no issue with LIMIT, issue is somewhere else.

Try to break query into pieces, and run each piece individually and then combine them one-by one to analyze.

***Response To Recommendation 1:*** That subquery works, however the issue is with the LEFT JOIN LATERAL. I have tried my query without the LIMIT 1 and it works fine... except it obviously returns too many results.

---

***Recommendation 2:*** Any Specific reason we are using LATERAL?

Try writing subquery using with clause and join it later.

***Response to Recommendation 2:*** Using LATERAL because I need exactly one record from the subquery to join to each record in the transaction table. LATERAL allows for the conditional aggregation to achieve that. I'm not quite sure what you mean by using the WITH clause. Are you suggesting a CTE?

---

***Recommendation 3:*** Maybe you can try removing LATERAL and also use MAX function instead of sorting subquery and getting limit, because essentially you need the latest rate after specified date but that was max by date will give you.

```
SELECT t.Amount, t.TrxDate, t.Currency, ex.ExchangeRate
FROM Transactions t
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT MAX(h.EffectiveDate ), h.Currency
FROM RateHistory h
WHERE t.TrxDate <= h.EffectiveDate
AND t.Currency = h.Currency
GROUP BY h.Currency
) ex
```

***Response to Recommendation 3:*** Since what I need is the the exchange rate for the max date, I'd need to select the exchange rate in that subquery as well, which means it would need to be grouped by and I'd end up in the same place; too many joins.

---

***Are there any other recommendations and/or work-arounds available out there??***

Answer (score 1):

use a window function to make sure you get only 1 row?

```
(SELECT Exchng_rate,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY exchng_dt DESC) as order 
        FROM    Curr_hist 
        WHERE Curr_Id = gl.curr_id
        AND Exchng_Dt <= gl.trx_date 
        ) 
where order=1
```

Answer (score 0):

So I moved the first LATERAL to a CTE which might not have been the problem. 
The second LATERAL is needing each rows `gl.tx_date` so if you just LEFT JOIN on that (which gives to way to many rows) and then use the `ROW_NUMBER()` to implement the filter you wanted with the `LIMIT 1`. Which makes me think this will be slow, but should work.

```
WITH cte_a AS (
    SELECT ap.reg_int_id
        ,ap.reg_seq_no
        ,MAX(ap.reference) AS reference
        ,MIN(aph.dist_dt) AS dist_dt
    FROM apdist ap
    LEFT OUTER JOIN aphist aph 
        ON ap.voucher_no = aph.voucher_no
    GROUP BY 1,2
)
SELECT Region,
   acct_no,
    trx_date, 
    source, 
    reference, 
    doc_no, 
    amount, 
    for_amt,
    reference2,
    reg_int_id, 
    reg_seq_no, 
    gl_curr_id, 
    chart_curr_id,
    reference3,
    dist_dt,
    cur_desc,
    exchng_rate
FROM (
    SELECT
        'SG' AS Region,
        CAST(gl.acct_no AS NUMERIC(12,6)) AS acct_no, 
        gl.trx_date, 
        source, 
        gl.reference, 
        doc_no, 
        gl.amount, 
        for_amt,
        reference2,
        gl.reg_int_id, 
        gl.reg_seq_no, 
        gl.curr_id AS gl_curr_id, 
        c.curr_id AS chart_curr_id,
        z.reference AS reference3,
        z.dist_dt,
        cur.cur_desc,
        ex.exchng_rate
        row_number() over (partition by gl.curr_id order by ex.exchng_dt DESC) as rn
    FROM gltrx  gl
    JOIN chart c 
        ON ROUND(c.acct_no,6) = ROUND(gl.acct_no,6)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN currencies cur ON gl.curr_id = cur.curr_id
    LEFT JOIN cte_a as z
        ON z.reg_int_id = gl.reg_int_id AND z.reg_seq_no = gl.reg_seq_no                  
    LEFT JOIN Curr_hist as ex
        ON ex.Curr_Id = gl.curr_id and ex.Exchng_Dt <= gl.trx_date 
    )
WHERE rn = 1;
```